# How to receive payment in Euro (using Stripe API) in Python

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to receive payment in *euro* but receiving in *usd*.
I made a website for France country, we need to accept money in *euro* currency but getting in *usd* by **Stripe** using `django`

[image]

Here is the code for stripe

```
if request.method == "POST":
    payment_type = request.POST["payment_type"]
    amount_dues = request.POST["amount_dues"]
    amount1 = request.POST["amount"]
    amount2 = amount1.split("€")
    amount = float(amount2[0])
    email1 = request.POST["email"]
    paid_amount = amount
    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
        email=request.POST["email"],
        name=request.POST["nickname"],
        source=request.POST["stripeToken"],
        address={
            "city": "kfhdksh",
            "country": "France",
            "line1": "566d ihflks",
            "postal_code": "77140",
            "state": "lfjkshkjsk",
        },
    )
    int_amount = amount * 100
    int_amount = int(int_amount)
    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
        customer=customer,
        amount=int_amount,
        currency="eur",
        description="charges for ride of Customer Id = "
        + str(myid),
    )
return redirect(reverse("success", args=[amount]))
```

Please help in getting currency in euro
What can I change in code or in stripe setting

Comment: It looks like you are using an old Stripe API using `token` and `charge`. Can you update your integration to use `Payment_Method` and `payment_intent` instead especially you are receiving payment in euro and you might need to be `SCA` compliant. Charge API is not SCA Compliant. You can follow step by step guide here https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements

Comment: To your question though, you are passing the right currency. The error might be somewhere else in your code

Comment: As an aside, you may wish to reconsider letting your client decide the `amount` to be charged :)